# Problems with retrieving json from request in Silex

Tags: json, upload, frameworks, xmlhttprequest, silex

The [Fronted Framework Uikit](http://getuikit.com/docs/addons_upload.html) provides some components (also with Javascript). I got in contact with the upload addon of Uikit, which provide a `xhr`(`xmlhttprequest`) based upload solution.
I am using the Mini Framework Silex which is a simplified symfony version.

For the `xmlHttpRequest` I defined this controller function:

```
   /**
     * Xhr Upload
     * -> for /add
     * 
     * @param Application $app
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function addAction(Application $app, Request $request)
    {
        if($request->request->has('files')) {
             $files = $request->get('files');
             /** do some stuff, like insert Uploads in DB or move them to Filesystem
        }
    }
```

Take first a look to the upload component: it does provide some customizations, e.g define the `xhr action` (called controller) or `param` (Post Query Key).

In my case I take the `/add action` for which I have the `addAction() controller`. For `param` I use  `files` (default POST key).

I am not able to get the sent param (a json string)! My question is about to get this param form the request.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is quite unclear. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, how you tried it and what didn't work?

Comment: Did you check the content of the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` object?

Comment: I checked it with $request->get('request') but this key was empty